# In Panels, how are the 2 given arguments in System's node_view created?

Tags: panels

In the Panel pages for System node_view (Node template) and term_view (Taxonomy term template), there is a variant that is already defined. This variant has 2 arguments, "Node being viewed" and "Depth". How are these arguments created?

thanks,

Eric J.

Answer (score 1):

Panels has by default some operations on url arguments which can create variables used in Panels. The short explanation is that Panels for nodes does a `node_load` on the node id which is part of the url: `node/[nid]`. It does something similar for taxonomy terms, only depth isn't the term itself, but rather information about it.

You can do this yourself if you create a custom url with placeholders, like `my-panels-url/%node` and assign the variable to be a node or taxonomy term.

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering my question. But I must apologize for my unclear question. What I meant was is how you create the 2 Arguments you see under Context of the variant "Panel" of the panel page System node_view. If I use Site building->Pages->Wizard->Node template, then I create a variant in the System node_view panel page, which has 1 Argument. But can it be done in another way too?

Comment: @ericj The last part of the answer answers this.